# Ranking Results Based on Points

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, nosql

I'm trying to build a function that retrieves a list of items but prioritizes them by some fairly complex relationships such as friend's votes and common interests. I could simply retrieve a list from the database then sort programmatically based on a point system, but it is very slow. Any ideas how I could do such a thing but faster?

I've looked into NOSQL and Elastic Search but it's not totally clear how I could implement this.

Here's some example code that is working (very slowly):

```
items = Item.all
friends = current_user.friends
items.each do |item|
   friends.each do |friend|
      if friend.liked_item?(item)
         item.points += 3
      end
      if friend.viewed_item?(item)
         item.points += 2
      end
      if friend.searched_item?(item)
         item.points += 1
      end
   end
   # continue like this for categories, friends of friends, etc
end

return items.sort_by {|item| item.points}
```

EDIT:

The items query is not the bottleneck, but rather that I have to retrieve 6 other tables and iterate through all the items based on 15 different criteria. Narrowing the amount of items would not help either because we still want to display items that were not liked by friends; the associations from other tables are meant to sort, not narrow the results.

Comment: Instead of returning every time, would it be acceptable to return only the items that your friends have searched / viewed / liked? That could potentially cut down the amount of items you need to iterate over. For this, just create a custom scope that would retrieve all of those items in a single call.

Comment: No because there will be some items after a point that were not liked by friends, and there is also a lot more criteria than just friends (eg. categories, dates, etc). I'm looking more to sort based on multiple criteria rather than narrow the data set.

Comment: Fetching all `items` from your table will of course slow things down. You have to figure out if you can build an association between item and users, that way you can just fetch the items needed and then update accordingly.

Comment: There are many relationships between users and items, however there are 6 different tables involved that need to sort the items. The slow part is not fetching the, but rather it is that friends, categories, friends of friends, etc all have to be fetched, and then iterated over. The items query is not the bottleneck.

Comment: And you have to do all that in one request? or is a background job/cron job which will be updating this?

Comment: Maybe doing all the process on the DB server via a function, storing the results on a temporal table, then displaying the results using a model for that temporal table?